# How can I get SQL print statements in Flyway logs?

Tags: java, flyway

I have an SQL stored procedure which prints a line when an exception occurs. But I am not getting any print statements in the Flyway logs, even though the DEBUG mode is ON.

```
 BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.sp_Test') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            EXEC dbo.sp_Test
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'Error occured';
        END CATCH 
    END
 COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported. Please file an issue and specify your DBMS type and version.

Comment: Issue 501 opened in Flyway.

Comment: Hi Axel, Could you please check issue 501